# Is there a name for the mathematical function f(x) = 0 when x=0 and 1/x otherwise?

Tags: functions, inverse

I'm using Octave, a programming language similar to MATLAB, and I would like to invert every value in a particular matrix.

But if I tell it to use the function `f(x) = 1/x`, it will display an error when `x=0`.

Is there a well-known mathematical function (preferably that Octave has code for) that is equivalent to `f(x) = 0 for x=0 and 1/x otherwise`?

I'm relatively new to stack exchange, so please let me know how to improve my answer (or improve it by editing it, especially through adding LATEX).

Comment: No, there isn't. Every piecewise defined function doesn't have its own name. In most programming languages you can define your functions, so why is this an issue?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 That's not really true.. What about the absolute value function?

Comment: @jacer2 I mean to say it's not the case that every piecewise defined function has its own name. I'm not arguing that none of them have a name.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Yes, I think I can, but I'm new Octave and finding out how to do so may be complicated. I also know that mathematicians will often name "nicer" functions like this function (which has a domain and range over all the reals, unlike plain old 1/x).

Comment: @ProQ How is this function nicer? It's not continuous on its domain.

Comment: @ProQ You can name it whatever you want, but mathematically it doesn't make a lot of sense to define $f(0)=0$ in your case, unless you share some background as to why you would choose it that way...

Comment: @imranfat its domain and range are all of the reals. That's the main reason.

Comment: Yes, if ,for whatever the Software reason, you need $y=1/x$ to have domain and range all reals, then $f(0)=0$ would be ok. Always known, I.T. remains weird sometimes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Some](https://www.vensim.com/documentation/index.html?fn_zidz.htm) computer [languages](http://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/functions/zidz.html) have a `zidz(a, b)` (=zero if divide by zero) function that returns $0$ if `b = 0` and `a/b` otherwise. The function you want would be a special case, `zidz(1, x)`. Octave doesn't have this as a built-in function, but you can write one simply enough.